# Gmail REST API - Mark message as read

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, gmail-api

I am trying to use the Gmail REST APIs to mark a message as read.

```
$('#markGmailRead').click(function(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer <<ACCESS KEY>>",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/<<MESSAGEID>>/modify',
        data: {"addLabelIds": ["UNREAD"]}
    })
    request.done(function(data){
        // when the Deferred is resolved.
        console.log(data);
    })
    request.fail(function(){
        // when the Deferred is rejected.
        console.log('fail');
    })
})
```

This results in the following json returned:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm at a loss as to what may be causing this.

Comment: Why does the title say `Mark message as read` and the data contain `"addLabelIds": ["UNDREAD"]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out and get it working. The only difference to be made was to stringify the data like so:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"removeLabelIds":["UNREAD"]}),
```

Making this change made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8" in the code. Also, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601767/google-api-create-a-new-calendar-parse-error) for the detail information on the error.

Let me know if you still see the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem doing this in Meteor. The problem was I was passing the removeLableIds in the 'params' attribute. Changing to the 'data' attribute worked, i.e.

```js
var apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/" 
     + messageID + "/modify";

var result = HTTP.post( apiUrl, {
        data: { "removeLabelIds": ["INBOX"] },
        headers:{
              "content-type":"application/json ; charset=UTF-8", 
              "Authorization": "Bearer " + tokens.accessToken 
        }
});
```